# Error initializing source docker://localhost/nginx:latest in Gitlab CI Pipeline

Tags: nginx, pipeline, podman, gitlab-ci.yml, buildah

I have a pipeline running for multiple stages in Gitlab. There is a stage that builds my own docker image. Building via

```
buildah bud --format docker -t
```

the execution fails when going through the steps of my Dockerfile, it has attempted to pull the latest nginx image:

```
STEP 13: FROM nginx:latest
error creating build container: The following failures happened while trying to pull image specified by "nginx:latest" based on search registries in /etc/containers/registries.conf:
* "localhost/nginx:latest": Error initializing source docker://localhost/nginx:latest: pinging docker registry returned: Get https://localhost/v2/: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:443: connect: connection refused
* "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": Error initializing image from source docker://nginx:latest: unsupported schema version 2
* "registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx:latest": Error initializing source docker://registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
* "registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest": Error initializing source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.access.redhat.com/nginx: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

There is nothing that I changed. Neither in the gitlab-ci.yaml nor in the Dockerfile I changed anything, but it suddenly doesn't work. The only change I discovered is the **CI_SERVER_VERSION**

A pipeline run through has been conducted successfully yesterday with the following ci server version

```
CI_SERVER_VERSION=16.7.0-pre
```

whereas the current version of the failed pipeline has the following version

```
CI_SERVER_VERSION=16.8.0-pre
```

Other than there seems nothing else different.

What can I do?

**EDIT:**

The stage that I am running uses the "buildah/buildah" image. When I try to pull the latest nginx image with podman

```
podman pull nginx
```

it fails and I get the following error

```
$ podman pull nginx
Trying to pull docker.io/nginx:latest...
Failed
Trying to pull registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx:latest...
Failed
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest...
Failed
error pulling image "nginx": unable to pull nginx: 3 errors occurred:
* Error initializing image from source docker://nginx:latest: unsupported schema version 2
* Error determining manifest MIME type for docker://registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.fedoraproject.org/nginx: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
* Error determining manifest MIME type for docker://registry.access.redhat.com/nginx:latest: Error reading manifest latest in registry.access.redhat.com/nginx: unauthorized: access to the requested resource is not authorized
```

I tried using an older image, for example nginx:1.21.6 and this version could be pulled. But I don't want to pull an older image.

It seems that the cause is an incompatibility between podman and the images? But how can I fix this?

Comment: The first error is `unsupported schema version 2` - could this be a docker-compose schema version and the new CI version only supports 3+?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this could relate to a docker-compose schema version since I only want to pull the nginx image? Anyway, I just rolled the version of nginx back by explicitly using a specific version